# Tap Win32 Adapter install failed

Tags: driver, openvpn, network-driver

The OpenVpn application needs an additional adapter to can work well. The Tap-Win32 virtual ethernet adapter will be installed during the application installation or can be added later.
Something went wrong, because I have tried everything, also running as administrator, troubleshooting, enable/disable, reinstall, but always will be going this to a failed status.

[image: tapinstall failed]

But without this adapter the connection will be failed too.
What can to do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is solved by downloading the newest standalone Tap driver from OpenVpn repository.